# Systemd boot hangs after disabling NetworkManager

Tags: systemd, networkmanager

I disable Network Manager via

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager
```

and reboot. The boot process hangs. Via whatever means, I access the filesystem, create symlinks with

```
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service \
/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service
```

And similarly for dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service. The boot process still hangs indefinitely after attempting to start the NTP daemon (NetworkManager is seemingly started without errors by that point).

Is there anything else I may need to do? Something other than symlink deletion affected by disabling the service?

Answer (score 2):

use init 1 which is single user without networking

use cmdline passing to kernel from grub i.e.

press e to edit on boot screen

you will see
find

> ro  quiet splash

and change it to

> ro  quiet splash single

and do

> systemctl enable NetworkManager